# jQuery functions' on Browser but not iPad

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications, ipad

I have the function below that works perfectly fine on all browsers. However, the function (which is used to log a user out essentially) doesn't work on the iPad(v3). Note this is a web-app.

My initial thought was it's `window.location`, which I've heard doesn't function well on iPad. But I tried `location.href` and `window.location.href` as well to no avail.

No console errors or strange behaviour.

Anyone experience any similar issues?

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', '.sb-sign-out', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    $.post('@Url.Action("clientLogout", "master")', {}, function () {
        window.location = "@Url.Action("campaigns", "master")";
    });
});
```

Here's the DIV:

```
<div class="sb-sign-out button round">LOGOUT</div>
```

Comment: can you expand on "doesn't work on the iPad"? Any noticeable errors? Strange behavior? No behavior at all?

Comment: No console errors, no strange behaviour. Works perfectly fine on all web browsers. Only iPad Safari and web-app it doesn't get fired...stressing...me....out! lol

Comment: take a quick look and make sure the `touchstart` is functional on your page. check [this blog post](http://miloq.blogspot.com/2011/05/detect-touch-devices-javascript.html) and let me know your results. If not functional, it could be a jquery version issue

Comment: touchstart works...I have it used through the web app. no issue there. I'm using jQuery "1.8.2".

Comment: shouldn't you be using touchend if you are using this as a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue, as mentioned in comments above, was that all non a-href buttons should be using `touchend` versus `touchstart`. This fixed my issue.

```
$(document).on('touchend click', '.sb-sign-out', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    $.post('@Url.Action("clientLogout", "master")', {}, function () {
        window.location = "@Url.Action("campaigns", "master")";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to make this work reliable is via the 'tap' event handler in jquery mobile, for example:
    $(document).on('click tap', elem, function (e) {});

see here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

for normal jquery this plugin would give you equal abilities:
http://plugins.jquery.com/tap/

the problem with touchend is that if someone touches the button, then decides to not log off and move the finger away from the button, it gets triggered although not wanted...

Comment: Yes, maybe. But I don't want to include another script for a few events I can just use with the normal jQuery. You know?